# How to use dot as splitter in currency format with Russian locale

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write currency in the format:

```
₽ 3 812.23
```

But if I select Russia as region in the table settings and format the string

```
₽ 0.00
```

result formatted number like

```
₽ 3 812,23
```

with a comma, because the comma is default separator in Russian locale. How to change comma to dot?

Comment: You have tagged with Google spreadsheet. Please read the description. It's off topic

Answer (score 1):

> How to change comma to dot?

Use Edit, Find and Replace...

[image: Find and Replace]

However the result is a text string, so you might need to substitute dot with comma if to calculate with the result.

Answer (score -2):

Go to "File" > "Spreadsheet settings" and modify the "Locale".

Comment: Hi Spiros, could you elaborate on your answer? What should the locale be set to?